# Smarty date variable. Add days, change format

Tags: date, format, smarty, days

I have a question about the date format in smarty.

I got a smarty variable: [{ $order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value }]

This variable give me: 2013-03-10 10:45:17

Now I want do add 14 days, remove the time and change the format of the date:

So my wish is now to get this: 24.03.2013

Is this possible and how can i do this directly in the smarty/.tpl file?

Thank you for help and greetings!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tested in Smarty **3**

`{"$order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value +14 Days"|date_format:'d.m.Y'}`

Comment: What kind of error you get? In Smarty 2.6.x I think you are forced to use the strftime format. You can try changing `date_format:'d.m.Y'` to `date_format:'%d.%m.%Y'`. See http://php.net/manual/de/function.strftime.php for more informations

Comment: I get no error but this output: "2013-03-21 11:29:31 d.m.Y" I also find just a few seconds ago this other format on the smarty page and give it a try ;)

Comment: Ok this works great :) Now i try to add the 14 days to the date.

Comment: This [{ "$order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value +14 Days"|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y" }} generate me a white page.

Comment: I am sure its a syntax thing but I am a noob at smarty!

Comment: [{ "$order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value +14 days"|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y" }] this give a white page.   

[{ $order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value "+14 days"|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y" }] and this give me the raw value (2013-03-10 10:45:17)

Comment: just frustating as a noob!

Comment: Ok, try: `[{ $order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value|cat:' +14 days'|date_format:"%d.%m.%Y" }]`

Comment: This works perfect :). You are my hero *thumbs up* and thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

I think a found a food way to do that :

```
{assign var="date" value= $order->oxorder__oxorderdate->value|@strtotime + (60*60*24*7)}
{assign var="date2" value=$date|date_format:"%d/%m/%Y"}
{$date2}
```

Change 7 value par the day you want ;-)